# jQuery each function for single and multiple elements

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have two types of JSON results:

```
{
 "person":{
  "fname": "Homer",
  "lname": "Simpson"
  }
 }

{
 "person":[
  {
  "fname": "Homer",
  "lname": "Simpson"
  },
  {
  "fname": "Marge",
  "lname": "Simpson"
  }
  ]
 }
```

I want to use a jQuery "each":

```
$.each(response.person, function(i, person){...
```

but "i" and "person" are different when JSON has one vs. multiple persons. 
I see the single person response does not have the array "[]", but when I:

```
$.each([response.person], function(i, person){...
```

then the multiple persons does not work.
I'm looking for a way to normalize things so that I may can use "each" consistently.

Comment: Is there any way for you to change how the results are generated?

Comment: Is this a response from YQL? yql does this with one result vs multi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test whether or not it is an array.

```
$.each(($.isArray(response.person) ? response.person : [response.person]), function(i, person){...
```

or you can modify the object prior to iteration:

```
if (!$.isArray(response.person)) {
    response.person = [response.person];
}
$.each(response.person, function(i, person){...
```

Comment: @bmw0128 I prefer Pills' solution, though.

Comment: i just saw the solution from Pills. It's good as well, but I saw Kevin's first, and I think they are fairly equal.

Comment: It's probably more performant to use Pills, and requires less typing, but most likely that would be a micro optimization. Use whatever is easier to understand. I was unaware of being able to convert an object to an array with `[].concat()`.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally you would have an array given to you initially, but you can always `.concat` the results to an empty array.  This will allow you to loop consistently:

```
$.each([].concat(response.person), function(i, person){...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MtzH8/

Comment: I knew this existed, was hard to find what i was looking for via google but here it is